# Can't build react app with webpack [problem with import[path]]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

**HI:**
I create react app with `create-react-app` 
and I need to use webpack to build my project to use it inside `Electron` as a desktop application

But after I run `webpack --mode development --watch`
webpack show next error

```
webpack is watching the files…                                                                                              

Hash: 7e114c5670c6d14690fd                                                                                                  
Version: webpack 4.20.2                                                                                                     
Time: 1636ms                                                                                                                
Built at: 2018-09-30 08:49:52                                                                                               
        Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names                                                                   
index-bundle.js   891 KiB    main  [emitted]  main                                                                          
    index.html  1.62 KiB          [emitted]                                                                                
Entrypoint main = index-bundle.js                                                                                           
[./index.js] 426 bytes {main} [built]                                                                                       
    + 45 hidden modules                                                                                                     

ERROR in ./index.js                                                                                                         
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'routes' in 'C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src'                           
@ ./index.js 5:0-28 10:23-29                                                                                               

ERROR in ./index.js                                                                                                         
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'store' in 'C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src'                            
@ ./index.js 4:0-35 9:9-23                                                                                                 

ERROR in ./index.js                                                                                                         
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'styles/global-styles' in 'C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src'             
@ ./index.js 6:0-30                                                                                                        

ERROR in ./index.js                                                                                                         
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utils/registerServiceWorker' in 'C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src'      
@ ./index.js 7:0-64 11:0-21                                                                                                
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":                                                                                 
    1 asset                                                                                                                
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html                                                                                       
    [../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!../public/index.html] 1.79 KiB {0} [built]                           
        + 3 hidden modules
```

My Project Structure

```
C:.
|   .editorconfig
|   .env
|   .eslintignore
|   .eslintrc.json
|   .gitattributes
|   .gitignore
|   .yo-rc.json
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   README.md
|   webpack.config.js
|   yarn-error.log
|   yarn.lock
|
+---generators
|   |   index.js
|   |
|   +---component
|   |       es6.js.hbs
|   |       es6.pure.js.hbs
|   |       index.js
|   |       stateless.js.hbs
|   |       stateless.pure.js.hbs
|   |
|   +---container
|   |       index.js
|   |       index.js.hbs
|   |
|   \---utils
|           componentExists.js
|           containerExists.js
|
+---public
|       favicon.ico
|       index.html
|       manifest.json
|
\---src
    |   index.js
    |
    +---actions
    |   |   counter.js
    |   |   index.js
    |   |   selectBook.js
    |   |
    |   +---blog
    |   |       appendNewPostToDom.js
    |   |       fetchBlogs.js
    |   |       removePost.js
    |   |       requestPost.js
    |   |       savePost.js
    |   |       selectPost.js
    |   |       showRemovePostDialog.js
    |   |       test_load_data_on_router_init.js
    |   |
    |   \---weather
    |           search.js
    |
    +---assets
    |       logo.svg
    |
    +---components
    |       BooksProject.js
    |       Counter.js
    |       Header.js
    |       index.js
    |       SparkLineWeather.js
    |       weatherProject.js
    |
    +---constants
    |       ActionTypes.js
    |       ApisKeys.js
    |       AutoConstCombination.js
    |       General.js
    |       URLs.js
    |
    +---containers
    |   |   BookDetailsContainer.js
    |   |   BookListContainer.js
    |   |   CounterContainer.js
    |   |   index.js
    |   |
    |   +---blog
    |   |       blogProject.js
    |   |       checkBox.js
    |   |       inlinePost.js
    |   |       newPost.js
    |   |       removePostDialog.js
    |   |       showBlog.js
    |   |       singlePost.js
    |   |
    |   \---weather
    |           googleMaps.js
    |           searchBarContainer.js
    |           weatherList.js
    |
    +---context
    |       index.js
    |
    +---middlewares
    |       promiseMiddleWare.js
    |
    +---reducers
    |   |   books.js
    |   |   bookSelected.js
    |   |   counter.js
    |   |   index.js
    |   |
    |   +---blog
    |   |       appendNewPostToDom.js
    |   |       fetchedBlogs.js
    |   |       fetchePost.js
    |   |       getRemovePostDialog.js
    |   |       postSaved.js
    |   |       selectedPostsIds.js
    |   |
    |   \---weather
    |           fetchedWeather.js
    |
    +---routes
    |       index.js
    |       router_callback.js
    |
    +---selectors
    |       index.js
    |       selectedPost.js
    |
    +---simulate
    |       helpers.js
    |       weatherdata.json
    |       WeatherMap.js
    |
    +---store
    |       index.js
    |       store.dev.js
    |       store.prod.js
    |
    +---styles
    |       global-styles.js
    |
    +---tests
    |       CounterContainer.test.js
    |
    \---utils
            registerServiceWorker.js
```

Package.json /webpack part

```
"reactRedux:webPack:build": "webpack --mode production",
"reactRedux:webPack:dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
"reactRedux:webPack:solve": "webpack -display-error-details"
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
require('dotenv').config();

console.log('OSAMA,',path.join(__dirname, "src"));
module.exports = {
context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
entry: "./index.js",
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index-bundle.js"
},
module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
    }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./../public/index.html"
    })
]
};
```

Now I can solve this proplem by modifying `src/index.js`

From

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from 'store'
import Routes from 'routes'
import 'styles/global-styles'
import registerServiceWorker from 'utils/registerServiceWorker'

render(
<Provider store={configureStore()}>
    <Routes />
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
)
registerServiceWorker()
```

To

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './store'
import Routes from './routes'
import './styles/global-styles'
import registerServiceWorker from './utils/registerServiceWorker'

render(
  <Provider store={configureStore()}>
    <Routes />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
registerServiceWorker()
```

But this will produce the next errro

```
Hash: fe8872d4e25816fb9eea
Version: webpack 4.20.2
Time: 12754ms
Built at: 2018-09-30 09:15:23
1 asset
Entrypoint main = index-bundle.js
[21] ./store/index.js 142 bytes {0} [built]
[27] ./utils/registerServiceWorker.js 3.91 KiB {0} [built]
[51] ./index.js + 43 modules 96.2 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./index.js 434 bytes [built]
    | ./styles/global-styles.js 1.72 KiB [built]
    | ./routes/index.js 1.81 KiB [built]
    | ./routes/router_callback.js 299 bytes [built]
    |     + 40 hidden modules
[52] ./store/store.prod.js + 3 modules 8.93 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./store/store.prod.js 529 bytes [built]
    |     + 3 hidden modules
    + 68 hidden modules

ERROR in ./routes/router_callback.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'actions' in 'C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src\routes'
@ ./routes/router_callback.js 4:0-51
@ ./routes/index.js
@ ./index.js

ERROR in ./routes/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'components' in 'C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src\routes'
@ ./routes/index.js 21:0-66 39:15-21 45:15-27 48:15-29
@ ./index.js

ERROR in ./routes/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'containers' in 'C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src\routes'
@ ./routes/index.js 20:0-78 42:15-31 51:15-26 54:15-22 57:15-23
@ ./index.js

ERROR in ./store/store.prod.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'reducers' in 'C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src\store'
@ ./store/store.prod.js 3:0-35 9:36-47
@ ./store/index.js
@ ./index.js

ERROR in ./routes/router_callback.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'store' in 'C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src\routes'
@ ./routes/router_callback.js 3:0-26
@ ./routes/index.js
@ ./index.js
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [0] ../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!../public/index.html 1.79 KiB {0} [built]
        + 3 hidden modules
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

and i know how to solve this error also `make all imports relative to ./src`

For example in `src/routes/router_callback.js`

Convert import From

```
import store from 'store';
import {testLoadDataInRouterInit} from 'actions';
```

To

```
import store from './../store';
import {testLoadDataInRouterInit} from './../actions';
```

And this will remove the error relative to `./routes/router_callback.js`

But it's not logically to go through all files and modify all imports
And I can't understand why `context` option in `webpack.config.json`
not solve this problem

So I need any solution to mark `./src/` as the root directory of import
Also if you can explain why webpack take this strange behavior

Or `ugly-solution` any tool to perform the path convert operation `eg. node package`

---

Solution Steps

I Solve The Problem By using resolve.alias

In webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
require('dotenv').config();

console.log('OSAMA,',path.join(__dirname, "src"));
module.exports = {
context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
entry: "./index.js",
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index-bundle.js"
},
resolve: {
    alias: {
    store:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/store/'),
    actions:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/actions/'),
    assets:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
    components:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
    containers:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/containers/'),
    constants:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants/'),
    context:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/context/'),
    selectors:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/selectors/'),
    middlewares:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/middlewares/'),
    reducers:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/reducers/'),
    routes:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/routes/'),
    simulate:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/simulate/'),
    styles:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/'),
    tests:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/tests/'),
    utils:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils/'),
    }
},
module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
    }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./../public/index.html"
    })
]
};
```

But now this Produce The next Error

```
Hash: d1dcce3dbddfd7e67373                                                                                                             
Version: webpack 4.20.2                                                                                                                
Time: 1565ms                                                                                                                           
Built at: 2018-09-30 09:53:04                                                                                                          
1 asset                                                                                                                               
Entrypoint main = index-bundle.js                                                                                                      
[0] ./index.js 1.93 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]                                                                                 

ERROR in ./index.js                                                                                                                    
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):                                                                  
ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src\index.js: Unknown option: .inherits. Check out https://babeljs.io/
docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.                                                                        
    at throwUnknownError (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:123:11)   
    at Object.keys.forEach.key (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:107:
5)                                                                                                                                     
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)                                                                                                     
    at validateNested (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:83:21)       
    at validate (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:74:10)             
    at instantiatePreset (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:244:36)                 
    at cachedFunction (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:33:19)                  
    at loadPresetDescriptor (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:235:45)              
    at config.presets.reduce (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:77:21)              
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)                                                                                                      
    at recurseDescriptors (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:74:38)                 
    at loadFullConfig (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:108:6)                     
    at process.nextTick (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:28:33)                     
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)                                                                     
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)                                                                     
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":                                                                                            
    1 asset                                                                                                                           
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html                                                                                                  
    [0] ../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!../public/index.html 1.79 KiB {0} [built]                                    
        + 3 hidden modules                                                                                                             
error Command failed with exit code 2.                                                                                                 
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The previous Error Related To `Babel`

---

I solve the previous problem
just set `.babelrc` as

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    ]
}
```

For me This produce a problem with `svg`

```
Hash: 0774fcb11803ab0dab91
Version: webpack 4.20.2
Time: 25132ms
Built at: 2018-09-30 10:12:21
1 asset
Entrypoint main = index-bundle.js
[3] ./constants/ActionTypes.js 665 bytes {0} [built]
[6] ../node_modules/redux-form/es/structure/plain/index.js + 6 modules 6.96 KiB {0} [built]
    |    7 modules
[22] ../node_modules/lodash-es/_baseGetTag.js + 2 modules 2.44 KiB {0} [built]
    |    3 modules
[55] ../node_modules/lodash-es/isArguments.js + 1 modules 1.48 KiB {0} [built]
    |    2 modules
[72] ../node_modules/lodash-es/_baseIsEqual.js + 22 modules 22 KiB {0} [built]
    |    23 modules
[73] ../node_modules/lodash-es/keys.js + 2 modules 1.83 KiB {0} [built]
    |    3 modules
[74] ../node_modules/lodash-es/isTypedArray.js + 2 modules 3.19 KiB {0} [built]
    |    3 modules
[82] ./simulate/helpers.js 1.01 KiB {0} [built]
[143] ./store/index.js 142 bytes {0} [built]
[144] ./reducers/blog/appendNewPostToDom.js 1020 bytes {0} [built]
[145] ./reducers/blog/selectedPostsIds.js 1.07 KiB {0} [built]
[219] ./assets/logo.svg 576 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[222] ./utils/registerServiceWorker.js 3.91 KiB {0} [built]
[470] ./index.js + 164 modules 500 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./containers/blog/removePostDialog.js 6.14 KiB [built]
    | ./index.js 426 bytes [built]
    | ./routes/index.js 1.81 KiB [built]
    | ./routes/router_callback.js 299 bytes [built]
    | ./containers/index.js 698 bytes [built]
    | ./containers/blog/inlinePost.js 6.49 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/singlePost.js 5.44 KiB [built]
    | ./styles/global-styles.js 1.72 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/CounterContainer.js 4.06 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/showBlog.js 5.7 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/newPost.js 9.83 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/blogProject.js 9.26 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/weather/weatherList.js 5.28 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/weather/searchBarContainer.js 4.22 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/BookDetailsContainer.js 2.89 KiB [built]
    |     + 150 hidden modules
[471] ./store/store.prod.js + 15 modules 41.4 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./store/store.prod.js 529 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/index.js 947 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/postSaved.js 475 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/counter.js 466 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/bookSelected.js 392 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/weather/fetchedWeather.js 1.2 KiB [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/fetchePost.js 447 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/books.js 196 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/getRemovePostDialog.js 569 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/fetchedBlogs.js 530 bytes [built]
    |     + 6 hidden modules
    + 551 hidden modules

ERROR in ./assets/logo.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
|   <g fill="#764ABC">
|     <path d="M65.6 65.4c2.9-.3 5.1-2.8 5-5.8-.1-3-2.6-5.4-5.6-5.4h-.2c-3.1.1-5.5 2.7-5.4 5.8.1 1.5.7 2.8 1.6 3.7-3.4 6.7-8.6 11.6-16.4 15.7-5.3 2.8-10.8 3.8-16.3 3.1-4.5-.6-8-2.6-10.2-5.9-3.2-4.9-3.5-10.2-.8-15.5 1.9-3.8 4.9-6.6 6.8-8-.4-1.3-1-3.5-1.3-5.1-14.5 10.5-13 24.7-8.6 31.4 3.3 5 10 8.1 17.4 8.1 2 0 4-.2 6-.7 12.8-2.5 22.5-10.1 28-21.4z"/>
@ ./components/Header.js 42:0-35 62:13-17
@ ./components/index.js
@ ./routes/index.js
@ ./index.js
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [0] ../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!../public/index.html 1.79 KiB {0} [built]
        + 3 hidden modules
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

---

I solve the `svg` problem 
By using [inline-react-svg plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg)

```
{
"presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
"plugins":[
    [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    {
        "loose": true
    }
    ],
    "inline-react-svg"
]
}
```

Also, we need to change import in header.js
From

```
import logo from 'assets/logo.svg'
```

To

```
import logo from '../assets/logo.svg'
```

Final Result

```
Hash: a38f27a1d8891a88af43
Version: webpack 4.20.2
Time: 24274ms
Built at: 2018-09-30 10:29:01
        Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
index-bundle.js   880 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
    index.html  1.62 KiB          [emitted]
Entrypoint main [big] = index-bundle.js
[3] ./constants/ActionTypes.js 665 bytes {0} [built]
[6] ../node_modules/redux-form/es/structure/plain/index.js + 6 modules 6.96 KiB {0} [built]
    |    7 modules
[22] ../node_modules/lodash-es/_baseGetTag.js + 2 modules 2.44 KiB {0} [built]
    |    3 modules
[48] ../node_modules/lodash-es/_Stack.js + 5 modules 2.78 KiB {0} [built]
    |    6 modules
[55] ../node_modules/lodash-es/isArguments.js + 1 modules 1.48 KiB {0} [built]
    |    2 modules
[72] ../node_modules/lodash-es/_baseIsEqual.js + 22 modules 22 KiB {0} [built]
    |    23 modules
[73] ../node_modules/lodash-es/keys.js + 2 modules 1.83 KiB {0} [built]
    |    3 modules
[74] ../node_modules/lodash-es/isTypedArray.js + 2 modules 3.19 KiB {0} [built]
    |    3 modules
[82] ./simulate/helpers.js 1.01 KiB {0} [built]
[143] ./store/index.js 142 bytes {0} [built]
[144] ./reducers/blog/appendNewPostToDom.js 1020 bytes {0} [built]
[145] ./reducers/blog/selectedPostsIds.js 1.07 KiB {0} [built]
[221] ./utils/registerServiceWorker.js 3.91 KiB {0} [built]
[469] ./index.js + 164 modules 501 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./containers/blog/removePostDialog.js 6.14 KiB [built]
    | ./index.js 426 bytes [built]
    | ./routes/index.js 1.81 KiB [built]
    | ./routes/router_callback.js 299 bytes [built]
    | ./containers/index.js 698 bytes [built]
    | ./containers/blog/inlinePost.js 6.49 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/singlePost.js 5.44 KiB [built]
    | ./styles/global-styles.js 1.72 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/CounterContainer.js 4.06 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/showBlog.js 5.7 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/newPost.js 9.83 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/blogProject.js 9.26 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/weather/weatherList.js 5.28 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/weather/searchBarContainer.js 4.22 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/BookDetailsContainer.js 2.89 KiB [built]
    |     + 150 hidden modules
[470] ./store/store.prod.js + 15 modules 41.4 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./store/store.prod.js 529 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/index.js 947 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/postSaved.js 475 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/counter.js 466 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/bookSelected.js 392 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/weather/fetchedWeather.js 1.2 KiB [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/fetchePost.js 447 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/books.js 196 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/getRemovePostDialog.js 569 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/fetchedBlogs.js 530 bytes [built]
    |     + 6 hidden modules
    + 550 hidden modules

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
index-bundle.js (880 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
main (880 KiB)
    index-bundle.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [0] ../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!../public/index.html 1.79 KiB {0} [built]
        + 3 hidden modules
Done in 26.76s.
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solve The Problem By using resolve.alias

In webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
require('dotenv').config();

console.log('OSAMA,',path.join(__dirname, "src"));
module.exports = {
context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
entry: "./index.js",
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index-bundle.js"
},
resolve: {
    alias: {
    store:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/store/'),
    actions:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/actions/'),
    assets:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
    components:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
    containers:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/containers/'),
    constants:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants/'),
    context:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/context/'),
    selectors:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/selectors/'),
    middlewares:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/middlewares/'),
    reducers:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/reducers/'),
    routes:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/routes/'),
    simulate:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/simulate/'),
    styles:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/'),
    tests:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/tests/'),
    utils:path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils/'),
    }
},
module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
    }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./../public/index.html"
    })
]
};
```

But now this Produce The next Error

```
Hash: d1dcce3dbddfd7e67373                                                                                                             
Version: webpack 4.20.2                                                                                                                
Time: 1565ms                                                                                                                           
Built at: 2018-09-30 09:53:04                                                                                                          
1 asset                                                                                                                               
Entrypoint main = index-bundle.js                                                                                                      
[0] ./index.js 1.93 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]                                                                                 

ERROR in ./index.js                                                                                                                    
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):                                                                  
ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\src\index.js: Unknown option: .inherits. Check out https://babeljs.io/
docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.                                                                        
    at throwUnknownError (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:123:11)   
    at Object.keys.forEach.key (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:107:
5)                                                                                                                                     
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)                                                                                                     
    at validateNested (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:83:21)       
    at validate (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:74:10)             
    at instantiatePreset (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:244:36)                 
    at cachedFunction (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:33:19)                  
    at loadPresetDescriptor (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:235:45)              
    at config.presets.reduce (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:77:21)              
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)                                                                                                      
    at recurseDescriptors (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:74:38)                 
    at loadFullConfig (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:108:6)                     
    at process.nextTick (C:\ncourses\nodejs\ElectronWorks\Combine\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:28:33)                     
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)                                                                     
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)                                                                     
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":                                                                                            
    1 asset                                                                                                                           
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html                                                                                                  
    [0] ../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!../public/index.html 1.79 KiB {0} [built]                                    
        + 3 hidden modules                                                                                                             
error Command failed with exit code 2.                                                                                                 
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The previous Error Related To `Babel`

So Any Soultion Or i need to post in in new Question

Answer (score 0):

I solve the previous problem
just set `.babelrc` as

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    ]
}
```

For me This produce a problem with `svg`

```
Hash: 0774fcb11803ab0dab91
Version: webpack 4.20.2
Time: 25132ms
Built at: 2018-09-30 10:12:21
1 asset
Entrypoint main = index-bundle.js
[3] ./constants/ActionTypes.js 665 bytes {0} [built]
[6] ../node_modules/redux-form/es/structure/plain/index.js + 6 modules 6.96 KiB {0} [built]
    |    7 modules
[22] ../node_modules/lodash-es/_baseGetTag.js + 2 modules 2.44 KiB {0} [built]
    |    3 modules
[55] ../node_modules/lodash-es/isArguments.js + 1 modules 1.48 KiB {0} [built]
    |    2 modules
[72] ../node_modules/lodash-es/_baseIsEqual.js + 22 modules 22 KiB {0} [built]
    |    23 modules
[73] ../node_modules/lodash-es/keys.js + 2 modules 1.83 KiB {0} [built]
    |    3 modules
[74] ../node_modules/lodash-es/isTypedArray.js + 2 modules 3.19 KiB {0} [built]
    |    3 modules
[82] ./simulate/helpers.js 1.01 KiB {0} [built]
[143] ./store/index.js 142 bytes {0} [built]
[144] ./reducers/blog/appendNewPostToDom.js 1020 bytes {0} [built]
[145] ./reducers/blog/selectedPostsIds.js 1.07 KiB {0} [built]
[219] ./assets/logo.svg 576 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[222] ./utils/registerServiceWorker.js 3.91 KiB {0} [built]
[470] ./index.js + 164 modules 500 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./containers/blog/removePostDialog.js 6.14 KiB [built]
    | ./index.js 426 bytes [built]
    | ./routes/index.js 1.81 KiB [built]
    | ./routes/router_callback.js 299 bytes [built]
    | ./containers/index.js 698 bytes [built]
    | ./containers/blog/inlinePost.js 6.49 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/singlePost.js 5.44 KiB [built]
    | ./styles/global-styles.js 1.72 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/CounterContainer.js 4.06 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/showBlog.js 5.7 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/newPost.js 9.83 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/blog/blogProject.js 9.26 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/weather/weatherList.js 5.28 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/weather/searchBarContainer.js 4.22 KiB [built]
    | ./containers/BookDetailsContainer.js 2.89 KiB [built]
    |     + 150 hidden modules
[471] ./store/store.prod.js + 15 modules 41.4 KiB {0} [built]
    | ./store/store.prod.js 529 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/index.js 947 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/postSaved.js 475 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/counter.js 466 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/bookSelected.js 392 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/weather/fetchedWeather.js 1.2 KiB [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/fetchePost.js 447 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/books.js 196 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/getRemovePostDialog.js 569 bytes [built]
    | ./reducers/blog/fetchedBlogs.js 530 bytes [built]
    |     + 6 hidden modules
    + 551 hidden modules

ERROR in ./assets/logo.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
|   <g fill="#764ABC">
|     <path d="M65.6 65.4c2.9-.3 5.1-2.8 5-5.8-.1-3-2.6-5.4-5.6-5.4h-.2c-3.1.1-5.5 2.7-5.4 5.8.1 1.5.7 2.8 1.6 3.7-3.4 6.7-8.6 11.6-16.4 15.7-5.3 2.8-10.8 3.8-16.3 3.1-4.5-.6-8-2.6-10.2-5.9-3.2-4.9-3.5-10.2-.8-15.5 1.9-3.8 4.9-6.6 6.8-8-.4-1.3-1-3.5-1.3-5.1-14.5 10.5-13 24.7-8.6 31.4 3.3 5 10 8.1 17.4 8.1 2 0 4-.2 6-.7 12.8-2.5 22.5-10.1 28-21.4z"/>
@ ./components/Header.js 42:0-35 62:13-17
@ ./components/index.js
@ ./routes/index.js
@ ./index.js
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [0] ../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!../public/index.html 1.79 KiB {0} [built]
        + 3 hidden modules
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the `svg` problem 
By using [inline-react-svg plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg)

```
{
"presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
"plugins":[
    [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    {
        "loose": true
    }
    ],
    "inline-react-svg"
]
}
```

Also, we need to change import in header.js
From

```
import logo from 'assets/logo.svg'
```

To

```
import logo from '../assets/logo.svg'
```